# Создать таймер на C#

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это расписание таймера: начало, интервал, параметр который он записывает в txt-вой файл и конец таймера. Работаю на console application в C#. Как сделать чтоб таймер работал так как показано на таблице.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я что-то не понял, что это за интервал такой. Начало + интервал, явно не сходятся с концом, но, в целом, для алгоритма это и не важно. Вам нужно сделать следующее:

- Заводите таймер-диспетчер, который будет срабатывать, скажем, каждую секунду.
- Читаете Вашу таблицу и составляете список таймеров: когда начать, на сколько ставить, и что делать по завершении.
- В событии timeout таймера диспетчера пробегаетесь по списку, и проверяете не пора ли нам начать какой-то таймер. Если пора, то удаляем данные из списка и создаём таймер, по timeout событии которого, мы будем писать наш текст в файл.
- Повторяем эти шаги, пока наш список не закончится, после чего можно завершать программу.

Пример создания таймера:

```
//Создаём таймер, который будет срабатывать каждую секунду
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
//Назначаем обработчик, который будет срабатывать по таймауту
timer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
//Таймер будет постоянно работать
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Где обработчик может выглядеть так:

```
private static void OnTimeout(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Timer expired");
}
```

Comment: Можете написать похожий пример)

Comment: @propro17, а что не понятно, из того, что я описал? Что Вы не можете сделать самостоятельно?

Comment: Покажите пример такого таймера в C# . И что такое time out

Comment: @propro17, обновил пост

Comment: мне нужно чтоб таймер автоматический создался в C# с параметрами, как показано в таблице. Можно ли так сделать?

Comment: @propro17: А почему бы вам не почитать документацию? Вы хотите, чтобы за вас написали весь код?

Comment: @propro17, параметры в таблице приведены для человека, их нужно адаптировать для машины. Так что ответ — нет, прямо взяв параметры из таблицы, нельзя решить Вашу задачу.

Comment: @ixSci Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @propro17, если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом.